# Is there a way to ignore file path using ack?

Tags: filter, ack

Lets say I have a folder with files like the one below:

```
.
|__  components
|    |__  index.js
|    |__  _index.js
|    |__  _index.en.js
|
|__  _.js
```

What I want is to search in `components/index.js` and in `_.js` and ignore all the `components/_*.js` files.

Basially I need something like ack's `--ignore-file=match:_.*\.js` but a version that also supports file's path.

Is it possible in ack 2?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `ack` doesn't have any direct support for ignoring certain files in subdirectories.

Another option is to combine `ack` with `grep` with something like the following:

```bash
ack -f | grep -v -x 'components/_.*\.js' | ack -x mystr
```

To explain:

`ack -f` prints the files selected, without actually searching.

`grep -v -x 'components/_.*\.js'` matches lines that *don't* contain the `_.*\.js` files under the `components` directory.

`ack -x` then reads the list of files to search from `grep`.

Of course, you can tailor the directories to ignore with `grep`.

Comment: It is not enough because I want to ignore these guys only inside the `components` folder.

Comment: I mean my example in description is simplified. The question is if it is possible to ignore not only filenames but file paths.

Comment: @chestozo I've totally revamped my answer to show an example that combines `ack` with `grep`.

Comment: Basically the whole point of my question is to say that ack is lacking this option that works well when you are using grep :) thank you for your answer.